# Stuck trying to use a customRestService and a serviceBean for a dojo Tree in XPages

Tags: java, rest, dojo, xpages, dijit.tree

I'm trying to create a dojo Tree, for the time being with test data. The bean always returns the same. When I put the data in a file inside the nsf Resources, it works. Using the bean, it fails. It displays only the word Continent, and I cannot open and descend the node.

Can someone help me out? I'd appreciate it enormously!

My code, where store2 works, store1 errors out and store0 only shows Continent:

```
                <xe:restService id="restService1" pathInfo="treeData">
                    <xe:this.service>
                        <xe:customRestService serviceBean="com.sefip.TreeData" requestContentType="application/json" requestVar="tree"></xe:customRestService>
                    </xe:this.service>
                </xe:restService>
                <!--
                    xp:text disableTheme="true" value="#{javascript:getBoxValue(compositeData.boxName)}" styleClass="readonly" style="margin-top:2px">
                    <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:getBoxValue(compositeData.boxName)}]]></xp:this.rendered> </xp:text> <xp:div id="boxTree"
                    dojoType="dijit.Tree"></xp:div
                -->

                <xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock2">
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[
    dojo.require("dojox.data.JsonRestStore");
    dojo.require("dojo.store.JsonRest");
    dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");
    dojo.require("dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel");
    dojo.require("dijit.Tree");

    dojo.addOnLoad(function() {

// Create a data store to retrieve data from

        var store0 = new dojox.data.JsonRestStore({
            //url: "countries.json"
            target: "aCRM2.xsp/treeData/",
            labelAttribute: "name"
        });

        var store1 = new dojo.store.JsonRest({
            target: "aCRM2.xsp/treeData/",
            labelAttribute: "name"
        });

        var store2 = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
            url: "countries.json"
        });


// secondly we create a treeModel. 
        var treeModel = new dijit.tree.ForestStoreModel({
            store: store0,
            query: {type: "continent"},
            rootId: "root",
            rootLabel: "Continents",
            childrenAttrs: ["children"]
        });

// Last but not least we create a new instance of our tree. 
        var tree= new dijit.Tree({
            model: treeModel
        },
        "#{id:treeOne}");
    });
    ]]></xp:this.value>
                </xp:scriptBlock>

                <!-- The domnode we will use to render the tree -->
                <xp:div id="treeOne" />

            </xp:div>
```

The countries.json contains:

```
{
    "items" : [{
            "id" : "EU",
            "children" : [{
                    "_reference" : "NL"
                }
            ],
            "type" : "continent",
            "name" : "Europe"
        }, {
            "id" : "NL",
            "type" : "country",
            "name" : "Netherlands"
        }
    ],
    "label" : "name",
    "identifier" : "id"
}
```

The bean generates exactly the same, but for completeness' sake I'll add the code here:

```
package com.sefip;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonException;
import com.ibm.commons.util.io.json.JsonGenerator;
import com.ibm.domino.services.ServiceException;
import com.ibm.domino.services.rest.RestServiceEngine;
import com.ibm.jscript.InterpretException;
import com.ibm.jscript.JSContext;
import com.ibm.jscript.json.JsonJavaScriptFactory;
import com.ibm.jscript.std.ArrayObject;
import com.ibm.jscript.std.ObjectObject;
import com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSUtility;
import com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.rest.CustomService;
import com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.rest.CustomServiceBean;
import com.ibm.xsp.util.JavaScriptUtil;

public class TreeData extends CustomServiceBean {

    @Override
    public void renderService(CustomService service, RestServiceEngine engine) throws ServiceException {

        HttpServletRequest request = engine.getHttpRequest();
        HttpServletResponse response = engine.getHttpResponse();
        String method = request.getMethod();

        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

        if (method.equals("GET")) {
            this.get(engine);
        } else if (method.equals("POST")) {
            this.post(engine, request);
        } else {
            this.other(engine);
        }
    }

    public void get(RestServiceEngine engine) {
        HttpServletResponse response = engine.getHttpResponse();
        try {
            JSContext jsContext = JavaScriptUtil.getJSContext();
            JsonJavaScriptFactory factory = new JsonJavaScriptFactory(jsContext);
            String json = null;
            ObjectObject returnJSON = new ObjectObject();
            returnJSON.put("identifier", FBSUtility.wrap("id"));
            returnJSON.put("label", FBSUtility.wrap("name"));
            ArrayObject countries = new ArrayObject();
            ObjectObject continent = new ObjectObject();
            continent.put("id", FBSUtility.wrap("EU"));
            continent.put("name", FBSUtility.wrap("Europe"));
            continent.put("type", FBSUtility.wrap("continent"));
            ArrayObject children = new ArrayObject();
            ObjectObject child = new ObjectObject();
            child.put("_reference", FBSUtility.wrap("NL"));
            children.addArrayValue(child);
            continent.put("children", children);
            countries.addArrayValue(continent);
            ObjectObject country = new ObjectObject();
            country.put("id", FBSUtility.wrap("NL"));
            country.put("name", FBSUtility.wrap("Netherlands"));
            country.put("type", FBSUtility.wrap("country"));
            countries.addArrayValue(country);
            returnJSON.put("items", countries);
            UserData.get().addLog("call generator");
            json = JsonGenerator.toJson(factory, returnJSON);
            UserData.get().addLog(json);
            response.getWriter().write(json);
            response.getWriter().close();
            return;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterpretException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void post(RestServiceEngine engine, HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpServletResponse response = engine.getHttpResponse();
        Map parameters = request.getParameterMap();
        try {
            response.getWriter().write("post()");
            response.getWriter().write(request.getParameter("form"));
            String[] form = (String[]) parameters.get("form");
            String val = form[0];
            response.getWriter().write(val);
            response.getWriter().close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

    }

    public void other(RestServiceEngine engine) {
        HttpServletResponse response = engine.getHttpResponse();
        try {
            response.getWriter().write("other()");
            response.getWriter().close();
            return;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

All this is largely based on the work done by Jeroen Somhorst and others, see http://www.jeroensomhorst.eu/uncategorized/viewpanel-vs-dijit-tree-part-1/ and part-2.

PS Dank je, Jeroen, maar waar is part-3?? ;-)

Comment: Are there any errors in the console of the server? 
If you open the developer tools of your browser what do you see happening? What does the rest call return?

Comment: No errors in the log, logreader, or in the developer tools. The rest call returns exactly the same as the content of the countries.json file. See the get() method above. I can also see in the Devtools/Network that the json is transferred, so everything seems correct. With store2 in the model, it works. With store0 it doesn't.

Comment: Did you check this URL http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/wa-jsonreststore/?ca=drs-?

Comment: Thanks!! Nope, I saw a lot of pages but I didn't see that one. I'll do some tests tomorrow. By the way, I have Domino R901, with dojo 1.9.7.

Comment: Finally, success! In fact, the JSON-structure for a FileStore and a JsonRestStore are completely different. The first is according to the countries.json file, the second is just a nested array with structures and children, like this... Oops, cannot use formatting here... I'll update the question.

Comment: Add an own answer with the solution. You can accept this answer later. This way people see that this question is solved.

Comment: Was at it... :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found a solution.

It turns out that the structure for a JsonRestStore should be a nested array with objects and children, like this:

```
[{
    "id" : "EU",
    "children" : [{
        "id" : "NL",
        "type" : "country",
        "name" : "Netherlands"
        }],
    "type" : "continent",
    "name" : "Europe"
}]
```

Plain and simple...

Thanks Jeroen, for the link, the comments in there showed me this way.